# checking a member's perms in D++

Tags: c++, discord, bots, d++

What's the most convenient way to check a users perms?
I've already read in the D++ docs that I have to use `dpp::guild_member_flags` (bitmask), but how do I use it correctly?
Is `dpp::guild_member_flags` even the correct way to check perms?

Comment: Why this question contains c++ tag..?

Comment: @K.R.Park D++ is a C++ library

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh, thank you for the information, I will cancel the downvote right away.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The downvote is locked! What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use [dpp::channel::get_user_permissions](https://dpp.dev/classdpp_1_1channel.html#adfb656e912fba27c809ab8754e2855b5) to get channel overwrites for someone or [dpp::guild::permission_overwrites](https://dpp.dev/classdpp_1_1guild.html#ad33639446c930d418139a976c9c1a071) to get their permissions in the guild. Note that they all use cache so if the user is not in cache, it will return `0`. To check if the returned permissions bitmask has a permission to something you are looking for, use `dpp::permission::can` member function and pass your permission as the argument, e. g. `dpp::p_send_messages` if you need to check if the member can send messages and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way to check a user's permissions is to use the dpp::guild_member_flags function. This function takes a bitmask as an input, which you can use to check the permissions that a user has.